# Forward slash in json file from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas

I'm a complete newbie to json, any help is appreciated.  I'm trying to convert a dataframe to a json file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1., 2.5],
                    'B' : ['img/blue.png', 'img/red.png']})
print df
```

Output is

```
    A             B
0  1.0  img/blue.png
1  2.5   img/red.png
```

I would like to make a json file that looks like this:

```
'[1.0,"img/blue.png"],[2.5,"img/red.png"]'
```

However, when I use the following

```
out = df.to_json(orient='values')[1:-1]
print out
```

I get this instead

```
'[1.0,"img\\/blue.png"],[2.5,"img\\/red.png"]'
```

How can I get the forward slash to print correctly in the json file?

Comment: I'm not certain but I believe you want those. I think the forward slash will break your json and needs to be escaped. Have you verified that the added back slashes are an issue?

Comment: Wow, you're right.  The added back slashes are not an issue. Thanks. Is there a way to upvote a comment?

Comment: there is a way. But don't worry about. I'll add as an answer and you can up vote that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain but I believe you want those. I think the forward slash will break your json and needs to be escaped. Have you verified that the added back slashes are an issue?

Comment: why should a forward slash break the JSON? The [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) says that a `/` **can** be escaped by a `\​`, but **not** that it **must** be escaped.

Comment: I wrote a test in python and in  java and both parsed the json (including slashes) with no  issues. The output is as  expected (no slashes). I personally  don't  know  why you would  want  the forward slashes escaped as  it seems unneeded but either way it  works fine .

Answer (score 20):

`pandas` uses the ujson library under the hood to convert to json, and it seems that it escapes slashes - see issue [here](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/252).

As a workaround, you could use the python standard library `json` module to dump the data - it won't be as performant, but won't escape the slashes.

```
import json

json.dumps(df.values.tolist())
Out[248]: '[[1.0, "img/blue.png"], [2.5, "img/red.png"]]'
```

Answer (score 7):

in the part where you are converting the pandas dataframe to json, if you will use `loads`, it will escape the `\` forward slashes

```
out = df.to_json(orient='values')[1:-1]
print out
```

try

```
import json
print json.dumps(json.loads(out))
```

for python 3:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(json.loads(out)))
```