# How to correctly convert the column in csv that contains the dates into JSON

Tags: python, pandas

In my csv file, the `"ESTABLİSHMENT DATE"` column is delimited by the slashes like this: `01/22/2012`.

I am converting the csv format into the JSON format, which needs to be done with pandas, but the `"ESTABLİSHMENT DATE"` column isn't correctly translated to JSON.

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv)
df.to_json("some_path", orient="records")
```

I don't understand why it awkwardly adds the backward slashes.

```
"ESTABLİSHMENT DATE":"01\/22\/2012",
```

However, I need to write the result to a file as the following:

```
"ESTABLİSHMENT DATE":"01/22/2012",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Forward slash in json file from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43413119/7758804) answers *why it awkwardly adds the backward slashes*, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413418/7758804) shows how to use the `json` library to solve the issue.

  - As long as the date format is `01/22/2012`, the `/` will be escaped with `\`.
- To correctly convert the column in a csv that contains the dates into JSON, *using pandas*, can be done by converting the `'date'` column to a correct `datetime dtype`, and then using `.to_json`.

  - `2012-01-22` is the correct datetime format, but `.to_json` will convert that to `1327190400000`. After using `pd.to_datetime` to set the correct format as `%Y-%m-%d`, the type must be set to a `string`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/22/2012']})

# display(df)
         date
0  01/22/2012

# to JSON
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
[out]: [{"date":"01\/22\/2012"}]

# set the date column to a proper datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y')

# display(df)
        date
0 2012-01-22

# to JSON
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
[out]: [{"date":1327190400000}]

# set the date column type to string
df.date = df.date.astype(str)

# to JSON
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
[out]: [{"date":"2012-01-22"}]

# as a single line of code
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y').astype(str)
```