# avoid pandas.to_json() to insert \ to the string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to send a pandas dataframe via RESTful API but when I use .to_json() to transform the dataframe into json, certain characters such as / has beeb modified by adding \ in front of it.

How could I avoid this behavior?

Example code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'title':'Google','URL':'https://google.com'},
                   {'title':'Facebook','URL':'https://facebook.com'}])
print(df.to_json())
```

Output:

```json
{"title":{"0":"Google","1":"Facebook"},"URL":{"0":"https:\/\/google.com","1":"https:\/\/facebook.com"}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413418/14066512

Comment: Thanks @RajeshC put the ```df.to_json()``` inside ```json.loads()``` do the trick.