# Backward slash when converting dataframe to json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

I tried to convert pandas dataframe to json. But a column in dataframe have path like structure (Example:/disk/folder/folder/file.txt).
Before each `/` forward slash, backward slash `\` is occuring.
**How to avoid backward slash.**

My dataframe:

```
    path                            time    content

0   /disk/folder/folder/file.txt    3.0     नमस्ते
1   /disk/folder/folder/file1.txt   4.0     नमस्ते
```

My code to convert pandas dataframe to json

```
with open('temp.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df.to_json(file, orient = 'records' ,force_ascii=False, lines=True)
```

Output Json file

```
{"path":"\/disk\/folder\/folder\/file.txt","time":3.0,"content":"नमस्ते"}
{"path":"\/disk\/folder\/folder\/file1.txt","time":4.0,"content":"नमस्ते"}
```

**Output Expected**

```
{"path":"/disk/folder/folder/file.txt","time":3.0,"content":"नमस्ते"}
{"path":"/disk/folder/folder/file1.txt","time":4.0,"content":"नमस्त"}
```

Help me out in this problem.

Comment: You are confused about directions. `/` is a regular (forward) slash and `\ ` is a backslash.

Comment: Yeah. Just now noticed. Thanks . Update: Now changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's alright. The backslash is used to [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) a string. It's possible that a forward slash has some special meaning in JSON or pandas, so it's escaped using a backslash. It should be alright if you load/use that JSON back.

---

#### EDIT 1

Interestingly, this does not appear to happen without Pandas.

```py
from json import dumps
print(dumps({"path": "/disk/folder/folder/file.txt", "time": 3.0, "content": "नमस्ते"}, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
{"path": "/disk/folder/folder/file.txt", "time": 3.0, "content": "\u0928\u092e\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0947"}
```

---

#### EDIT 2

Looks like someone beat me to the answer: [Forward slash in json file from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413119/forward-slash-in-json-file-from-pandas-dataframe)

---

#### EDIT 3 - Full solution by OP for easier understanding

dataframe

```
    path                            time    content

0   /disk/folder/folder/file.txt    3.0     नमस्ते
1   /disk/folder/folder/file1.txt   4.0     नमस्ते
```

dataframe to dictionary of records

```
dict_records = dataframe.to_dict('records')

dict_records
[{'path': '/disk/folder/folder/file.txt', 'time': 3.0, 'content': 'नमस्ते'},
 {'path': '/disk/folder/folder/file1.txt', 'time': 4.0, 'content': 'नमस्ते'}]
```

dictionary to json by dumping using ndjson library

```
import ndjson
with open('sample.json', 'w') as f:
    ndjson.dump(dict_records, f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

sample.json

```
{"path": "/disk/folder/folder/file.txt", "time": 3.0, "content": "नमस्ते"}
{"path": "/disk/folder/folder/file1.txt", "time": 4.0, "content": "नमस्ते"}
```

If you want to install ndjson - refer [ndjson Package](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/)

Comment: Good question why Python adds this superfluous backslash, though. The slash does *not* have any special meaning in JSON.

Comment: @tripleee you're right. I don't have much experience with `pandas`, but using `json` (see code as an edit to my answer), this doesn't happen. The Hindi/Devnagiri being converted to ASCII-safe makes sense though (but doesn't happen in OP's code??)

Comment: OP  (and @tripleee if you're curious), I've linked you to an answer. Please let me know if that helps you.

Comment: But if I use Dumps, Hindi/ devanagiri characters are converted to ASCII. Is there any way to avoid this convertion.

Comment: Set the argument `ensure_ascii=False` (edited into my answer). But make sure you want to do this: it's ASCII-safe by default for a reason.

Comment: `dumps` allows you to disable forcing strings to pure ASCII; though again,   you probably shouldn't care how exactly your JSON is formatted as long as it works.

Comment: OP, of this sorts your query, could you please accept the answer? (If not, I'm happy to help further)

Comment: I could not dump the dataframe directly. So, after converting the dataframe to dict, I tried to dump. If I do so, all the records are in comma seperated, enclosed in a list. But I want the records to be in row-wise. The expected output is reached only when converting dataframe directly to json like I said in question. But it includes backward slash.

Comment: Update: It can be solved using ndjson library.                                                                           ```import ndjson```
```with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:```
   ```ndjson.dump(dict, f,ensure_ascii=False)```